# HTTP Basic Authentication with PHP socket

Tags: php, rest, authentication, curl, https

So, I'm trying to use PHP Http sockets to execute a rest action on a distant server.

My goal is to have my PHP script automatically execute various actions that I usually perform when browsing "manually".

The distant website is an e-commerce oriented portal (no name provided) and connection is through HTTPS (I think that may be the problem here).

[There is no hacking here, just automation!]

I manage to execute several actions with my script like logging in to the website using my username and password, adding items to my cart etc.
Using Firebug I found that the action triggered for confirming order is /createOrder, but when I try to validate my order using my script with my session cookies I get a **401 Unauthorized error** (detailed below)

So I tried several times to access this action with CURL using my usual username and password but I never manage to get access.

How is it possible that I could access it by browsing manually but not with my script? Is there a way to make it work?

Response headers include:

```
Server: Apache
X-Cnection: close
Content-Length: 1518
WWW-Authenticate: Basic realm="WebLogic Server"
X-Powered-By: Servlet/2.5 JSP/2.1t
```

*"The request requires user authentication. The response MUST include a WWW-Authenticate header field (section 14.46) containing a challenge applicable to the requested resource. The client MAY repeat the request with a suitable Authorization header field (section 14.8). If the request already included Authorization credentials, then the 401 response indicates that authorization has been refused for those credentials. If the 401 response contains the same challenge as the prior response, and the user agent has already attempted authentication at least once, then the user SHOULD be presented the entity that was given in the response, since that entity MAY include relevant diagnostic information. HTTP access authentication is explained in section 11."*

Comment: Where's the *code*? Have you compared your browser requests and the Curl requests?

Comment: They are the same requests. The code has nothing to do with it I think. The problem is more of the HTTP Authentication protocol misunderstanding

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved.
It was a cookie issue.
I was not sending the token cookie correctly.